# eloquent, retrieve user data with foreign table data

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I have some foreign tables where I store generic common data for users, example 'Gender'. What I am trying to do is retrieve the logged user data along this foreign data. If I do this:

```
$id =  Auth::id();

$user = User::find($id);

echo $user;
```

or

```
$user = Auth::user();

echo $user;
```

I correctly get the authenticated user. But, if I try to retrieve the data I need like this:

```
$id =  Auth::id();

$user = User::find($id)->with('Gender');

echo $user;
```

All the users in the user table show up! How's that possible?

Comment: Can you try `Auth::user()->with('Gender');` ?

Comment: yes it throws an error: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

I found out there is no need at all to retrieve the data using the with('something) method.

This will work:

```
$user = Auth::user();

echo $user->gender;
```

And will get all the data from the foreign table.

Comment: this will result in a N + 1 problem which will cause performance issues at the long run. php is case sensitive so this would work Auth::user()->with('Gender'); try this instead Auth::user()->with('gender')

Comment: is the gender an attribute or a table

Comment: Gender is a foreign table. The user table has a 'gender_id' column.

Comment: can you show the related function in your user class

Comment: `public function gender(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Gender', 'id', 'gender_id');
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104338/discussion-between-oseintow-and-chriz74).